# Why does a reverse reaction occurs everytime?

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium

In a chemical reaction, I have studied that a reverse and forward reaction occurs every time and neither reactant nor product can be zero.

**My question is:** if the forward reaction and the backward reaction take place at a particular temperature then how can both the backward and forward reaction take place every time simultaneously?

Answer (score 2):

Reactions are probabilistic.  When the reagents come together, probability determines whether they're in the right state to combine.  For example, the molecular orientation needs to be favorable.  Sometimes thermal energy is needed to make a reaction likely.

Forward and reverse reactions don't necessarily take place everywhere simultaneously.  For the reaction $A+B\to AB$, the forward reaction occurs where A and B comes together, and the reverse reaction occurs where AB is split.  In that sense, the reactions occur in different places.  However, we often hand-wave away these discrete microscopic events and instead assume a continuous material.  There are an awful lot of molecules, so this is a pretty reasonable assumption.  In that sense, we always have a mixture of A, B, and AB, so both reactions can be thought of as occurring at the same time.

Comment: Explain my question with reference to rate of dissolution of salt snd rate of crystallisation of salt in water??

Comment: @Physicsstudent if you had wanted a specific example used in the answer then you should have specified it in the question. It isn’t nice to add surprise parts of the question later.

Comment: My bad sorry

Comment: @Physicsstudent it should be noted that salt dissolving and crystallizing is a physical phenomenon, not a chemical reaction.

Answer (score 2):

Chemical reactions are governed by a single fundamental interaction: electromagnetism.

And the laws of electromagnetism are time-reversible. So if molecules A and B can collide to form products C and D, then the probability that C and D will collide to form A and B as products is exactly the same as the probability of the forward reaction. In particular, the probability of the reverse reaction can never be zero. This implies that no reaction is truly irreversible unless at least one of the products escapes from the system entirely.

Note, however, that the probabilities are only equal under the assumption of a particular exact state. To give an extreme example, when a molecule of [octanitrocubane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octanitrocubane) decomposes into 8 carbon dioxide molecules and 4 nitrogen molecules, it is conceivable that at some later point in time, those 8 carbon dioxide molecules and 4 nitrogen molecules might come together with the exact momenta, impact parameters, molecular orientations, and excitation levels that they had when they were initially formed. If that were to happen, they would have the same probability of reforming the octanitrocubane molecule as the latter originally had to decompose into them. However, the probability that they do, in fact, meet under those exact circumstances is astronomically small. This is why, at equilibrium, there is practically no octanitrocubane.

Comment: Please tell this reference to temperature

Answer (score 1):

The forward and reverse reactions should be understood in a statistical sense. Suppose a crystal of a salt is in equilibrium with the dissolved salt and the equilibrium concentration is $c^*$. Microscopically fluctuations take place all the time, for example, a few atoms of the crystal may dissolve causing the concentration in solution to increase somewhat. In the next instant perhaps some dissolved salt attaches to the crystal, or perhaps more salt from the crystal goes in solution.

In this picture the concentration of the salt is not fixed in time. Equilibrium says that on average the concentration of the dissolved salt fluctuates around its equilibrium concentration. On average then, for each molecule of salt that dissolves another molecules from solution attaches to the crystal.

The crucial term here is *on average*, so it is possible for the concentration of salt to keep increasing or decreasing for a while. Nature works in such ways that the tendency of dissolved salt to crystallize increases as the concentration exceeds the equilibrium value. Similarly, the tendency of the solid to dissolve increases when the concentration falls below equilibrium. This prevents the concentration from changing too much from its equilibrium value.

There is a mechanical analogue for this, the pendulum: for every time the pendulum passes from left-to-right it will pass from right-to-left; and the more it moves away from the equilibrium point the bigger the force that tries to bring it back.

**On the effect of temperature** Dissolution equilibrium is established over a range of temperatures. The effect of temperature is to *shift* the value of the equilibrium concentration to a higher or lower value. Very qualitatively, the net rate of dissolution (rate of dissolution minus rate of recrystallization) is
$$
   R_\text{dissolution} - 
   R_\text{cryslallization}
  = K(c^*-c),
$$
where $c$ is the actual concentration in solution, $c^* = c^*(T)$ is the equilibrium concentration, a function of temperature, and $K$ is some factor, also a function of temperature. Equilibrium is established when this difference is zero. Since $c^*$ varies with temperature, this condition can be satisfied at many different temperatures.

Comment: You did not tell this with reference to temperature

Comment: What I describe takes place at any temperature. What do you mean “with reference to temperature”?

Comment: What my question actually was is that why does crystallization occurs at any temperature if crystallisation needs a specific temperature to occur

Comment: That’s not what I understand from the question as asked. Anyway, temperature simply *shifts* the equilibrium, i.e., it changes the equilibrium concentration that balances the forward and reverse rates. I will update my answer to explain.